# RUNTIME ERROR - NZEC in simple PYTHON code

Tags: python

```
def sort(a,n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            if a[i]<a[j]:
                t=a[i]
                a[i]=a[j]
                a[j]=t
n=input()
a=[]
i=0
j=0
q=0
for i in range(0,n):
    x=int(raw_input())
    a.append(x)
sort(a,n)
for i in range(0,n-1):
    if a[i+1]==a[i]+1:
        q=q+1
if q==n-1:
    print "YES"
```

The above is the solution to a Hackerearth problem, being new to python i am facing this NZEC error which bothers me a lot as i got no solution for this error.

Can someone please tell me why am i getting this error and whats the solution for the same

Comment: but your code runs fine in your system?

Comment: YES!!!!! It runs perectly

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code is not working is because of this

```
n = input()
```

You are using `n` again as

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

range wants an Int number as input.

Hacker earth will show NZEC regardless of the problem it faces. It is upon you to figure out the problem. One good way is to use Try and Except blocks.
Simply adding this will lead to a lot of easier debugging

```
try:
     YOUR CODE DOING STUFF
except Exception as E:
     print(f"Error occurred::: {E}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `NZEC` stands for `Non zero exit code` error.

You can probably try to put the entire code inside a `try..except`. Where the `except` just ignores the `exception`. Try if this works.

```
try:
  your_function()
except Exception: 
  pass
```

So put your entire code inside `try..except` try this,

```
try:
  entire_code()
except Exception: 
  pass
```

Where `entire_code()` is:

```
def sort(a,n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            if a[i]<a[j]:
                t=a[i]
                a[i]=a[j]
                a[j]=t
def entire_code():
    n=input()
    a=[]
    i=0
    j=0
    q=0
    for i in range(0,n):
        x=int(raw_input())
        a.append(x)
    sort(a,n)
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        if a[i+1]==a[i]+1:
            q=q+1
    if q==n-1:
        print "YES"
```

Or maybe even try to print the `stacktrace` in the `except` block.

Comment: THANKS!! for the prompt reply but on doing this only the exception block is running not the try block.